# Access: Update query with list of users

Tags: ms-access

I have an access db with some tables, queries, macro... etc
One table is a result of a query and it's used to populate a sharepoint. This table has a column [User] that has no records but I would like to fill with a list of users before upload to the sharepoint.

Ex. the table has 58 rows and I whant to use the 10 users.

Row1 - User 1

Row2 - User 2

...

Row10 - User 10

Row11 - User 1

and so on...

I realy don't know what is the best way to do this.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Not quite understanding. You mention table has no records but then describe a table that has 58 rows.

Comment: He said the column has no records - I think what he means is that there are records, its just that the user column is all blank / null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) for this.

Create a new Module and then create a procedure that will populate the data.
Its relatively simple - you want to loop through all the users and update the parent table.

For my code, I am assuming that you have one table holding your query results (with the empty "User" field), and that you have another table holding all of your users (using the field name "UserName")

```
Public Sub PopulateUsers()
  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Dim rstUsers As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rstComputers As DAO.Recordset

  ' Open up our tables
  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  Set rstUsers = dbs.OpenRecordset("Users")

  ' If there are no users then complain and quit
  If rstUsers.EOF Then
    rst.Close
    MsgBox "There are no users to populate", vbInformation, "Error"
    Set rstUsers = Nothing
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set rstComputers = dbs.OpenRecordset("ComputerUsers")

  ' Loop through all of our computer records
  Do Until rstComputers.EOF
    rstComputers.Edit
    rstComputers!User = rstUsers!UserName
    rstComputers.Update
    rstUsers.MoveNext
    If rstUsers.EOF Then
      rstUsers.MoveFirst
    End If
    rstComputers.MoveNext
  Loop

  ' Close tables
  rstUsers.Close
  rstComputers.Close

  ' Clear object references to free up memory
  Set dbs = Nothing
  Set rstUsers = Nothing
  Set rstComputers = Nothing

  debug.print "Users Populated"
End Sub
```

You can press Control + G to open the immediate window and then type "PopulateUsers".

Comment: Thanks DHW this is exactily what I need. Now I just need to findout why is the loop not ordering the users.

Comment: If you want the users ordered, then you can either create an ordered Query for users and replace the dbs.OpenRecordset("Users") or you can embed the SQL directly: dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY UserName")